# 404 Not found returned when Spring Boot war deployed in Tomcat Docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

I am deploying a Spring Boot project war to container running tomcat. But it gives 404 for every request. Its on java 8

Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:8
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "vim"]
COPY target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Application.java

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Updated the web.xml. changed url patter from / to /*

```
 <!-- The mapping for the default servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

```
docker build -t my-app:latest .
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local" -v /Users/sachintiwari/Desktop/web.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/web.xml -p 8080:8080 -t my-app:latest
```

the image gets built & container runs successfully

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: What's the name of your jar? As far as I remember it must be `ROOT.war` in order to work like this. Otherwise it will be deployed under a context path with the same name as the war file. E.g. if it is `myapp.war` you have to make a request to `/myapp/api/v2-docs`.

Comment: Download the war file locally and try to run it in a local Tomcat server. Check the jar as well, might be a case of a missing spring-boot-maven-plugin or gradle plugin

Comment: @nsawaya it runs on local tomcat server

Comment: found any fix for this ? facing same issue.

Comment: haven't found any yet

Comment: @SachinTiwari Did you find any solution?